# How should I handle pdfs, word documents, and excel spreadsheets with Subversion?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have been using Subversion at my current position for just over one year.  It was one of the first things I did here.  I immediately implemented it as there was no versioning control of any kind in place.

Last year, I imported our entire site into Subversion.  I imported it exactly as it was, garbage and all.  PDFs, images, frontpage _vti_cnf folders, EVERYTHING.

I felt this would allow me to safely make any changes to the site, and give me a starting point to be able to track changes progress, etc...

Now a year later, I'm a little upset with some of the way I set this up.  Mainly I want to figure out a better way to handle binary documents.  **I do not want to put binary files in my repository. period.**

### Please note

Images, are different. TortoiseSVN can compare images, and they are a different animal. They would affect the look or feel of the site. This is not the case for pdfs, word docs, excel, access dbs, zip files, movies, etc...

---

Here is the process for how we manage website updates to production.  Updates to the site are done weekly, after the site is updated I create a tagged copy for that week.

1. I get a request to update a pdf with a new version, and change the hyperlink text to have some new description
2. I update my working copy to the latest version, I make the html code change to the site.
3. I copy the new version of the pdf file into my working copy, replacing the old pdf with the new.
4. At this point, my working copy shows 2 pending changes, though only one is actually a code change.  PDFs are just content.
5. I `commit` both changes to my repo.
6. Now when it's time to move to production, I compare my trunk with last week's tag folder.
7. TortoiseSVN is able to generate an export of only the files that need to be updated on production, with full paths.  I do this so I can alway have the root copied over to the production site.
8. I export the files and empty folder structures to a location where another team picks it up and copies it over to production.

So using this method, both the code change and the PDF get moved to production.  But, I don't like it.

My other problem, with not using the above process is that I also don't trust my memory to remember during every move to production to manually copy the pdfs into my changeset prior to moving to production.

Comment: Having binary files in version control is fine is not necessarily bad.  Do you seriously object to images in version control?  Without those files you only have half of your site; you can't 'test' it as easily.

Comment: Images, are different. TortoiseSVN can compare images, and they are a different animal. They would affect the look or feel of the site. This is not the case for pdfs, word docs, excel, access dbs, zip files, movies, etc... Also, since I am not aware of the content, the content person could send me a pdf of their Will instead of the correct document,  I can't test that, I wouldn't know the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using something like Nexus or Artifactory for storing these documents? Yes, these programs are for managing Maven repositories, but there's no reason you have to be using Maven to use them.

The advantage:

- Via the web interface, they can download the documents themselves into the repository. That eliminates one point where the "Finger o' Blame" can point to you. No more, "You put the wrong copy into the release. No, you gave me the wrong one." arguments.
- When you do the release, you can get the revision you need automatically through a build process.
- Files are still "versioned". They're not under version control system that stores them as diffs, but if you have to redo last month's release, you have the right versions of the PDFs to pull.
- They can add in the documents for next month's release, and not wait until the last minute. You'll pull the files for this month's release because you know the release. With Subversion, you were probably pulling in the latest.

Another possibility is to use something like [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com). The interface is so simple that even a manager can use it. And, as a bonus, Dropbox also versions all of the documents for you. You create a shared Dropbox between them and you, and they simply put the documents they want in that directory.

The problem with Subversion isn't the binary files, but the fact that you are stuck because Subversion is really too complex for people with no technical training to handle. (Thus, you get the files and you put them in the repository). A release repository like Artifactory or Nexus can get you out of the loop.

Comment: I think there is an assumption that this is a responsibilty issue.  Truely these files get updated once in a blue moon.  The problem is my repo is 3GB when it should probably on be 10Mb.  Content comes from "Everyone"  there is no "departement" to speak of.

Comment: All the more reason to use a release repository system like Artifactory and Nexus. Things stored in a release repository aren't usually stored "forever" as they are in source control. Obsolete versions are easily managed and removed. Unless they need the power offered by a source control system, they don't need one.

Comment: How does this help me get the right version of the file when I go to production? I see lots of info online to get artifacts into Artifactory, but not to publish them.

Comment: Artifacts can be retrieved via Maven commands (Yes, you can use Maven to talk to a Maven repository even if your project isn't Maven based) with Ant/Ivy combination, or simply via wget. In the end, a Maven repository is just a http server with a particular format for the location of the files.

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://docs.sonatype.com/display/SPRTNXOSS/Nexus+FAQ#NexusFAQ-Q.HowcanIretrieveasnapshotifIdon%27tknowtheexactfilename%3F

Comment: Wowee.  This all seems like using a mini-gun to swat flies.  Those solutions require a big learning curve for me and the rest of the staff.

Comment: @DavidW. let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2416/discussion-between-doug-chamberlain-and-david-w)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is content for the website that get updated by someone other than the site's web coding team.  Let's call these crazy content updaters "Marketing", just for fun.  Right now, the process is that they give the files to you, you check them in, then you push them to your production team.

Having the files in version control is not the problem; the problem is that you are the middleman.  You're never going to refuse a PDF update, so why put yourself in that position?  Don't be the middleman; work towards disintermediation.  Either:

**A.** Give Marketing permission to update the files directly in Subversion themselves, or
  **B.** work with the production team to give Marketing a separate place where they can deliver the files directly.

Note that Marketing might well still benefit from having their PDF files (or better yet, the source files that they generate the PDFs from) in version control; you obviously know the benefits so maybe you can convince them (show them how to diff!).  But it doesn't have to be *your* repository, if you are really opposed to that for some reason.

Comment: For sure externals could help, depending on how you want to use them.  BTW I didn't mean that you could diff PDFs easily, but if they are generating PDFs from e.g. word docs then they should put the word docs in version control (and Word lets you compare copies).  Sounds like you are going with a combination of a) and b) -- good call.

Comment: I think I really like the idea of only dealing with the originals alot!.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to create a second repo in svn.  Call it htdocs, it can get as bloated as it needs.

I'll link it as svn:external to my actual repository.

No fuss.  No muss.